# Installing slide shower rail outlet elbow

Tags: shower, fitting

I bought [this](https://www.victorianplumbing.co.uk/trafalgar-traditional-shower-slide-rail-kit-chrome) shower and wondering the best way to install the outlet elbow. There is currently one in the shower but it doesn't seem fixed to the back well or probably at all.

I have full access behind the wall and wondering what kind of fitting I should install so that the elbow can screw in properly. The directions are less than helpful. The elbow doesn't have anyway to affix it to the wall and seems it's meant to screw into a fitting.

For reference we're in the UK.

Update: (@jsotola)
Thought I'd add some pictures of the back to see what I'm dealing with. Looking for suggestions on affixing it to the wall. Thinking of using my wood to build bracing. The wall is made from air brick (very porous and kinda soft)

[This is the mixer we're going to use](https://images.victorianplumbing.co.uk/images/pdf/CSV12.pdf)

Currently the back of the outlet elbow. Doesn't look attached to the wall in any way
[image: Currently the back of the outlet elbow. Doesn't look attached to the wall in any way]

Back of the current mixer which will be replaced. Only secured by the copper pipes right now.
[image: Back of the current mixer which will be replaced. Only secured by the copper pipes right now.]

I thought I'd give you a glimpse of the plumbing I"m dealing with in this house. None of the wires are live. We're already disconnected those but still need to remove them.
[image: rube goldberg plumbing]

Comment: please add a clear, well lit photo of the "behind the wall" area ... use tape to mark the desired location of the elbow

Comment: @jsotola I just updated the posting with pictures of how the mixer and elbow are currently attached. Looking for idea's on how best to secure to the back wall. I was thinking of using some ply and 1x material to make bracing.

Comment: @kyle I added some pictures to show the back. Thoughts on adding blocking to secure the pipes? It's a solid wall of air brick.

Comment: That's an... interesting... mix of plumbing parts. At the bottom left of the pic, there's plastic that comes out of the wall then 90° up, then a short, bent PVC pipe before it hits copper. I'd suggest loosening the top 90° elbow and twisting it so that the PVC pipe isn't curved. That's a likely future failure point because of the bend. I'd suggest cutting the longer, lower PVC pipe as well, so that the PVC after the 90° isn't bent, as well.

Comment: Noted. Not sure what the thinking was to go from 22 copper -> 15 copper -> 22 plastic for those pipes. That plastic goes to the bathtube and somewhere under the floor tee's off to the sink. Guess where the water for the toilet comes from? :-) Then there is a pipe going over the bathroom, through a wall down to the ground floor bathroom sink. Only for cold water mind you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outlet elbow seems to have male threads- In the US that is NPT threads either 1/2" or 3/4"- could be different in UK.

[image]

The installation should be similar. We use what is called a "drop ear 90"

[image]

This has female sweat fitting (to attach to copper pipe) on one side and female threads on the other side. This can be affixed to blocking in the wall (usually screwed) so that the pressure of tightening the outlet elbow would not put undo pressure on the drop ear 90. Usually there is no way to get a back up wrench inside the wall.

Care must be taken with the placement of this drop ear 90 so that the outlet elbow can be tightened against the finish shower wall enough to seal the joint and also enough so that it can sit nicely against the wall. This drop ear 90 can be set further into the wall (deeper) and then an appropriate sized nipple (2 male ends) with a coupling (female to female) can be put together to bring the female end to the correct position relative to the finish shower wall.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That's kinda what I was thinking but forgot about the different nipples. Fittings like this are 1/2" here.

Comment: Question: I see a lot of [brass all thread nipples](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Threaded-Running-Plumbing-Fitting-Connectors/dp/B089NC1Z2Y). Are those meant to be cut to to the length you need?